# Exposed Service ClusterIps aren't accessible within Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-proxy

I've been working at this, and I'm not making any progress.

The issue is that when I create a service out of a deployment, the ClusterIp that's created for the service isn't accessible within MiniKube as I expect it should be.

I can verify that it's not accessible by sshing into a different pod than the one I've exposed, and pinging the IP of the service.

`kubectl expose deployment/foo --target-port=2500`

This creates the service at 10.0.0.5, which routes to ${foo's IP}:2500

`kubectl exec -it bar-5435435-sadasf -- bash
root@bar-5435435-sadasf:/# ping 10.0.0.5`

`PING 10.0.0.5 (10.0.0.5): 56 data bytes
^C--- 10.0.0.5 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss`

I have no issue pinging the pod IP ($foo's IP), but that's not what I want to do.

I've done enough reading to know that the issue is likely related to `proxy.go` which seems to be the `kube-proxy` equivalent in Minikube.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/localkube/proxy.go

I've checked out the Minikube logs and grepped for anything containing "proxy", and it seems this might point to the issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

My latest proxy logs:

`Sep 06 18:13:06 minikube localkube[3373]: Starting proxy...
Sep 06 18:13:06 minikube localkube[3373]: Waiting for proxy to be healthy...
Sep 06 18:13:07 minikube localkube[3373]: proxy is ready!
Sep 06 18:46:47 minikube localkube[3373]: E0906 18:46:47.742324    3373 proxy.go:207] Error proxying data from backend to client: write tcp 192.168.99.101:8443->192.168.99.1:58760: write: broken pipe
Sep 06 19:11:41 minikube localkube[3373]: E0906 19:11:41.077014    3373 proxy.go:193] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 127.0.0.1:44180->127.0.1.1:10250: write: broken pipe
Sep 06 19:11:41 minikube localkube[3373]: E0906 19:11:41.077220    3373 proxy.go:207] Error proxying data from backend to client: write tcp 192.168.99.101:8443->192.168.99.1:45586: write: broken pipe
Sep 06 19:22:07 minikube localkube[3373]: E0906 19:22:07.214287    3373 proxy.go:207] Error proxying data from backend to client: write tcp 192.168.99.101:8443->192.168.99.1:51558: write: broken pipe
Sep 06 19:22:07 minikube localkube[3373]: E0906 19:22:07.214459    3373 proxy.go:193] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 127.0.0.1:45184->127.0.1.1:10250: write: broken pipe`

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: k8s services don't reply to ping requests, was that the only thing you tried for checking the connection?

Comment: Thanks, Marc. So being able to ping services isn't something I was 100% on, but I used the ping example for simplicity. The real problem I'm having is setting up the host IP for my db. I want to use the service IP, but I can't find the host when I do. When I use the pod IP, everything works as expected. I don't think port mapping is the issue. I've been thinking it's all `kube-proxy` because that seems to be the key piece in the documentation, and it's not running on my system. Have I just missed something really obvious here?

Answer (score 3):

A Service gets its Virtual IP address using the ClusterIP. That IP address is used for communicating with the Service and is accessible only within the cluster.

Make sure that you connect to a service not only by its IP but also with the port that service exposed.

In your case:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment/foo --port=3030 --target-port=2500

$ kubectl get svc 
NAME  CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
foo   10.0.0.73    <nodes>       3030/TCP        1m
```

Now the service is reacheable from within a cluster:

```
$ minikube ssh
$ curl 10.0.0.73:3030
Hello World!
$ exit

$ kubectl exec -i -t bar-j26rd /bin/sh
$ curl 10.0.0.73:3030
Hello World!
$ exit
```